# How to split equity fairly when contributions differ?

Tags: real-estate, equity

I understand there are a few similar questions here but for this I'm going purely by numbers for a fair equity split of residential property. I've rounded the numbers for ease.

I'm interested in equity per party at purchase, equity now, and a formula for the equations. Happy to provide more information if required. Appreciate the help

Edit:

Maybe I never phrased the question clearly initially.

I'm looking for a fair division of the equity based on contributions at the time of purchase and again now.

Just the raw numbers. Everything else is irrelevant.

**Property**
Purchase price: 1,300,000
Current value: 1,500,000
Additional loan: 100,000
Current owing:  1,100,000

**Party A.**
Deposit: 220k
Payments: 25k
Total:   245k

**Party B.**
Deposit:  20k
Payments: 25k
Total:    45k

Note: The additional Loan for 100,000 was used equally by both parties for something unrelated. All I am asking is for the raw numbers and a formula

Comment: If you had 240K deposit for 1300K of property, shouldn't the loan have started out as 1060K owing? How is it 1100K now? If it's rounding, I think you've oversimplified this a bit, you should make the numbers consistent.

Comment: Was there no discussion up front?

Comment: There has been an additional loan against the property, hence the 1,100,000 owing.

Comment: @NotLeonhard what was the additional loan used for? Improving the property? And how much was it?

Comment: It was used equally by both partys for something unrelated, hence was left out of the equation initially. Remember all I am asking is for the raw numbers and a formula 

Comment: @NotLeonhard looks like you need to get your [accounts merged](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: "Just the raw numbers - everything else irrelevant". Actually the *only* thing that is relevant is what the parties already agreed to. Fair can mean a lot of things. You can't 'math' your way out of a social problem.

Comment: Raw numbers don't matter to lawyers when they start arguing sweat equity, and intangibles like "knowing the right person" or "having the Excellent credit score".

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to divide the equity pro rata based how much has been paid in overall at each point in time.

At the time of purchase, Party A had paid 220k/240k (91.7%) and Party B had paid 20k/240k (8.3%).  So the $200k in equity would have been split into $183,333 for party A and $16,667 for party B.

If you sell the property for $1.5M, and pay off the $1.1M in debt, you have equity of $400,000 left over.

Party A has paid 245k/290k or 84.5%. Party B as paid 45k/290k or 15.5%. Therefore you could split the equity proportionally, giving Party A $338,000 and Party B $62,000.

Note that there is no *legal* requirement to split it one way or another - as long as you can both agree on how to split it. But, pro-rata is a "fair" method.

Comment: I agree with this. To make it slightly more sophisticated, don't include any interest / property tax / insurance payments in the "ending equity" totals. I.e., only add the principal payments to the original equity total.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to pay back the deposits first to each person. For the amount that is left you could a few things:

1. Divide the remainder equally (80,000 to each person)
2. Divide the remainder into 11/12 and 1/12 to reflect the percentage paid of the total deposit

Now this may be idiosyncratic on my part, but if party B had reasons why they couldn't put in a larger deposit like they're significantly younger (less time to save), not working outside the home, less education so unable to work at a high-paying job, etc., you could look at this as an opportunity to help them 'catch up.' You could do that by taking just your deposit amount and letting party B have the rest, splitting the entire amount equally, or after you recoup your deposit, taking a modest extra amount (20-30k) and letting party B have the rest.

Answer (score 1):

'fair' can be very subjective. Others might consider fair as it is considered by default  in a marriage 50/50 to both parties. Certain parties might have offered their knowledge and experience as utility instead of money, others might be young and could not afford the same contribution as the elders. Unless it is contractually spelled out, it is really up to you (and your partners) to decide what is 'fair'.